# On the Predual of $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$

Tags: functional-analysis

The question is already indicated as in the title, is it possible to find a normed space $X$ such that the continuous dual $X^{\ast}$ is isomorphic to the Euclidean Lebesgue space $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$?

Having discussed with a professor, he said, if it were true, then it will contradict the Banach-Alaoglu Theorem: The closed unit ball $B_{1}(0)$ of $L^{1}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ is weak$^{\ast}$-compact.

I still fail to see why there is such a contradiction.

Comment: Lacey H.E. (1974) L1-Predual Spaces. In: The Isometric Theory of Classical Banach Spaces. Die Grundlehren der mathematischen Wissenschaften (in Einzeldarstellungen mit besonderer Berücksichtigung der Anwendungsgebiete), vol 208. Springer, Berlin, Heidelberg.

Comment: We cannot say that the ball of $L_1$ is or isn't compact before we agree on which weak* topology we're talking about.  The weak* topology is NOT the same as the weak topology.  It in fact determines the space $X$ we're loking for, should it exist:  namely the set of all weak* continuous linear functionals!

Comment: The reason why $L^1$ is not a dual space is a bit more complicated.  Its ball does not have any extreme points, so being a dual would contradict Krein-Milman.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Ruy is right.  $L^1(\mathbb R^n)$, with the usual Lebesgue measure, is not linearly homeomorphic to the dual of any Banach space.  For example, one reason is that it is a separable space that fails the Radon-Nikodym property.

A nice reference on this material is

*Diestel, J.; Uhl, J. J. jun.*, Vector measures, Mathematical Surveys. No. 15. Providence, R.I.: American Mathematical Society (AMS). XIII, 322 p. $ 35.60 (1977). [ZBL0369.46039](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0369.46039).